# MySQL - Group by for UNION query

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I've been trying to find a solution to my problem for a couple of hours now and can't come up with the right query. I have two tables, stocktake_scans and stocktake_items. I need to select data from both tables and group them together. The query that I have at the moment is this:

```
SELECT 
a.department_description, a.sub_department_description, a.total_cost, a.total_retail, SUM(a.qty) AS qty, a.total_vat, a.vat_rate 
FROM ( 
    SELECT (CASE WHEN TRIM(IFNULL(sp.department_description, '')) = '' THEN 'N/A' ELSE sp.department_description END) AS department_description, 
    (CASE WHEN TRIM(IFNULL(sp.sub_department_description, '')) = '' THEN 'N/A' ELSE sp.sub_department_description END) AS sub_department_description, 
    SUM(sp.unit_cost_price * ss.quantity) AS total_cost, 
    SUM(sp.unit_retail_price * ss.quantity) AS total_retail, 
    sum(ss.quantity) AS qty, 
    (SUM(sp.unit_cost_price*ss.quantity)) * (sv.vat_rate/100) AS total_vat, 
    sv.vat_rate as vat_rate 
    FROM 
        stocktake_scans ss 
        INNER JOIN stocktake_products sp ON ss.stocktake_product_id = sp.stocktake_product_id 
        LEFT JOIN stocktake_vat_codes sv ON sv.vat_code = sp.vat_code AND sv.stocktake_id = '5778' 
        WHERE ss.stocktake_id = '5778' 
        GROUP BY sp.department_description, sp.sub_department_description 
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT (CASE WHEN TRIM(IFNULL(si.department_description, '')) = '' THEN 'N/A' ELSE si.department_description END) AS department_description, 
        'N/A' as sub_department_description, 
        SUM(si.unit_cost_price * si.quantity) AS total_cost, 
        SUM(si.unit_retail_price * si.quantity) AS total_retail, 
        sum(si.quantity) AS qty,
        SUM(si.unit_cost_price * quantity)*(sv.vat_rate/100) AS total_vat, 
        sv.vat_rate as vat_rate 
        FROM stocktake_items si 
        LEFT JOIN stocktake_vat_codes sv ON sv.vat_code = si.vat_code AND sv.stocktake_id = '5778' 
        WHERE si.stocktake_id = '5778' GROUP BY si.department_description ) a 
    GROUP 
        BY a.department_description, a.sub_department_description
```

This doesn't fully do the job. I get all the data from stocktake_scans, followed by data from stocktake_items.

I get the below as the first result
[image: Image 1]

And then at the end of the excel file I also get this

[image: Image 2]

What is the right way of doing this, so that both Alcohol figures are displayed in one place?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: `This doesn't fully do the job.` so what job should do? Show us sample data current output and expected output.

Comment: But I did say what is the current output and what I am expecting. As I said, I get two results for Alcohol department, one from scans table, other one from items table. As can be seen on the images, there are in two separate locations in the excel file. My expected result is to have them grouped together so that the Alcohol department is not duplicated.

Comment: Try summing everything (apart from your group by items) in your outer query,

Answer (score 0):

Add `ORDER BY a.department_description, a.sub_department_description` before the last `GROUP BY`